# How to send photos of dead animals to Cletus

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

After I completed the Strangers & Freaks mission "Fair Game" with Cletus, he said I could kill animals, send a photo of them to him and he would pay me.
I've run over a few Coyotes and deer since then and taken photos with my snapmatic, but all it does is add the photo to my online gallery.
How do I send the photo to Cletus for my payday?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To activate the hunting minigame, you need to travel to the icon on the map, that looks vaguely like an elk head, and enter the trailer at this location. Trevor then gets the animal call and a sniper rifle with unlimited ammo.

A crude image of the hunting icon:

[image]

Comment: hmm so I can't just kill random animals for cash?

Comment: No, you have to activate the minigame first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on PC and the instructions for sending a photo are not loading on the bottom right screen below the picture after you take it..... It's spacebar. I had to go through every button to figure that out

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to remove the "grid" from the picture before you snap it. Do that then take the picture. After you take the picture without the "grid"you have the choice of texting the picture to someone.....pick Cletus and there you go!

Comment: Does that really work, have you tested it? The already accepted answer says that that shouldn't work.